# Calling an Oracle store procedure with nHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure in Oracle:

```
procedure Test(results OUT gencursor, id in number) is
  v_cursor gencursor;
begin
OPEN v_cursor FOR
          select id, name, age from tblcustomers s where s.id = id;
results:=v_cursor;
end Test;
```

Now, i'd like to execute this procedure using nHibernate `ISession.CreateSQLQuery`. All the examples I've seen until now use `ISession.GetNamedQuery()`.

So, I'd want to do something like (`ToDataTable` is my own extension method on `IQuery`, I have more extension methods which I'd want to stay using in combination with stored procedures):

```
        var result = session
            .CreateSQLQuery("call MyPackage.Test(:id)")
            .SetDecimal("id", 33)
            .ToDataTable();
```

The code above throw the following exception:

> "could not execute query [ call
>   MyPackage.Test(?) ]   Name:id - Value:33
>   [SQL: call MyPackage.Test(?)]"

I've also tried:

```
        var result = session
            .CreateSQLQuery("call MyPackage.Test(:result, :id)")
            .SetDecimal("id", 33)
            .ToDataTable();
```

That one throw the exception:

> Not all named parameters have been
>   set: [result] [call MyPackage.Test(:result,
>   :id)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now if you can call sps from CreateSQLQuery, but I'll show you how we call Oracle sps from NHibernate in my current project:

```
var query =  _session.GetNamedQuery("MyPackageTestSp");
            query.SetParameter("id", 33);
            query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

In a mapping file the named query is defined like so:

```
<sql-query name="MyPackageTestSp">
    call MyPackage.Test(:result, :id)
</sql-query>
```

Works like a charm :-)

Comment: I guess I'm more struggling with mapping the ouput cursor with nHibernate. How does your approach handle output results? I read in the manual that the requirements are the output should be in the first parameter (as a cursor).

Comment: This answer worked great for me, but I noticed a couple things: it looks like Martin put "call" twice inside of the sql-query node. I only needed one to get it working. Also, MAKE SURE you do not leave a trailing semicolon after your call xxx( ... ) statement. I had call xxx( ... ); and it took me hours to figure out the nonsense error message Oracle was spitting out at me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it easier to just use a view.  In your mapping, just set mutable=false on your class so it can't be updated.  The view should create the level of abstraction your are trying to achieve.